# Trouble finding visionOS section in Xcode template chooser

Tags: ios, xcode, vision-pro

I'm currently working on developing a visionOS app, and I'm encountering an issue with finding the visionOS section in the Xcode template chooser. I have Xcode version 14.3.1 (14E300c) installed and have also downloaded the Xcode 15 beta 4 package. However, when I try to create a new project, I can't find the visionOS section in the template chooser as mentioned in the Apple documentation.

I have already checked for compatibility between the Xcode version and visionOS, but I'm still unable to locate the appropriate section

Answer (score 1):

> ...For development with the visionOS SDK, continue to use Xcode 15 beta 8.
>
> -- https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/

Comment: Yep. For now, it looks like you need a beta version of Xcode in order to work with visionOS (which is still in beta)